# Why assets precompile says "canot load such file fog-aws"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, assets, fog

I have added fog to my gemfile and run bundle, after that assets:precompile. Gives me that fog-aws can not load. Then add fog-aws too, gives same thing. In project used ruby 1.9.3

What's wrong, i don't understand

What can i do to solve this?

Thanks..

[image]

Comment: Could you update and post your gemfile? I've had an issue before where I received 'cannot load such file' because of grouping.

Comment: Sorry @livepo , i mess to include link to me github gist https://gist.github.com/sdilshod/9693ee89a4e580e85d43

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem with line code in CarrierWave config.

I leave only fog gem in Gemfile and remove line of code from CarrierWave.configure "config.fog_provider = 'fog-aws'" and rename this file name from carrierwave.rb to fog.rb .

Its work for me.